# How to automatically map camelcase to snakecase in Spring Data Cassandra?

Tags: spring, cassandra

First, I know how to directly map via @Column.

However, directly mapping to all fields is cumbersome.

Is there any setting or way to automatically map fields that I declare as camelcase (Spring) to snakecase (DB)?